# Cancel A WinForm Minimize?

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize

I have a winform with the minimizeMaximizeClose buttons disabled, but still if someone presses it in the task bar, it will minimize.  I want to prevent this from happening.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably catch them changing it in the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) event and check the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx), if its been set to [Minimized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate.aspx) then set it back [Normal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate.aspx). Not the most elegant solution but should work.

eg.

```
private void myForm_SizeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (myForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
   {
       myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
   }
}
```

Comment: This should also work, but since the event is triggered after the window was minimized it's slightly possible that a flickering effect will appear.

Comment: @Adrian: yeah I was just thinking that, depends what is on the form and how much redrawing would need to take place.

Comment: And what if the window was maximized? You need to know the window state prior to the event firing.

Answer (score 19):

Override WndProc on your form, listen for minimize messages and cancel.

Add this code to your form:

```
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112; 
private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xf020; 

 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{ 
    if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) 
    { 
        if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MINIMIZE) 
        { 
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; 
            return; 
        } 
    } 
    base.WndProc(ref m); 
}
```

I modified [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34224/rob)'s code found in this SO thread:
[How to disable the minimize button in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319124/how-to-disable-the-minimize-button-in-c)

Works great: no flickering, no nothing when the user attempts to minimize.

Comment: It should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's suitable for you, just hide it from the taskbar: `ShowInTaskbar=false`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply remove the minimize button from the window:

add the code below to the private void InitializeComponent() method of the Form class:

```
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
```