# How to override the minimize control?

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize

I want to override the minimize control to instead of sending the window to the taskbar it would do what ever I write it to do.

Basicly this is what I wanted my new minimized and restored effects to be:

```
    private void ChangeForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Height = 80;
            iDebug.Visible = false;
            mainMenu.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Height = 359;
            iDebug.Visible = true;
            mainMenu.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to fire an Event on the Resize to do this but without success

```
this.Resize += new EventHandler(ChangeForm);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cancel A WinForm Minimize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737053/cancel-a-winform-minimize)

---

Just tested this and it will make the form 100 pixels shorter when minimize is clicked without flicker.

```
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xf020;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) {
        if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MINIMIZE) {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            Height -= 100;
            return;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not prevent the window from minimizing it will minimize and restore from what I undestood and tested. What I want is to have my own function for when the user clicks the minus button that should minimize the window.

Comment: Check the other answer that talks about overriding the WndProc to cancel the minimize.  Then you can run your custom code after that.

Comment: thanks overlooked that due to the correct anwser beign marked.

Answer (score 3):

The Minimize command has a very well defined meaning to a user, it shouldn't be messed with.  Winforms accordingly doesn't have an event for it.  But not a real problem, you can detect any Windows message by overriding WndProc().  Like tihs:

```
    private void OnMinimize() {
        this.Close();   // Do your stuff
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Trap WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE
        if (m.Msg == 0x112 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0xf020) {
            OnMinimize();
            return;        // NOTE: delete if you still want the default behavior
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```