# mdi child form maximized windowstate - BorderStyle

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I want to open a child form inside parent with maximized windowstate.

I don't want to let the user minimize/ maximize/ close that child window,

so I set `BorderStyle = None` for childwindow and also set `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties  to `False`, also set `WindowState = Maximized`

But when I run the program it shows all `Minimize`, `Restore` and `Close` buttons for that childForm in maximized state.

but if I click `Restore Down` then there is no border for that childForm..now No way to restore it to maximized state also..

Am I missing something? Is this a bug? What is the proper way of making it work correctly?

Comment: This is just not the proper way to use MDI.  It only gets in the way if you try to keep a child window maximized.  Use a tabbed interface or swap UserControls to switch views.

Comment: look at this link in stackoverflow may help you
[How to disable the minimize button in C#?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319124/how-to-disable-the-minimize-button-in-c

Comment: did you try dock panel?

Answer (score 1):

just try this one.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const int SC_MOVE = 0xf010;
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
            if (command == SC_MOVE)
                return;
            break;

    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create your own  form(custome form) and then inherite that custom form into mdi child form

you have to place the below code in "custom Form"

```
   public partial class BaseForm : Form
   {
       public BaseForm()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation;
           MaximizeBox = false;
           Width = 806;
          //Width = 850;
          //Height = 760;
           Height = 730;
          //Width = 790;
          //Height = 617;
    }

//[DllImport("user32.dll")]
//[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
//private static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);
//private enum ScrollBarDirection { SB_HORZ = 0, SB_VERT = 1, SB_CTL = 2, SB_BOTH = 3 } 


protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
  const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
  //ShowScrollBar(this.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_BOTH, false);
  switch (m.Msg)
  {
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
      int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
      if (command == SC_MOVE)
        return;
      break;
   }
   base.WndProc(ref m);
 }
}
```

you must and should put your mdi child form `minimum size to '0'`  and  `size to Width = 806;  Height = 730;`

I hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Dont set it to maximised, Just set the width and height of the MdiParent...

```
Height = this.Height;
Width = this.Width;
```

this.Width should be the parent form

Hope this helps, If it does not. Drop me an email :)

beanlovin@gmail.com

Comment: `this.Height` and `this.Width` will set horizontal and vertical scrollbars because, child window should be smaller than parent window excluding the title bar and the borders..

Answer (score -1):

```
Form1 fr = new Form1(); 
fr.MdiParent = this; //set form's parent to Mdiform
fr.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None; //set form without maximize,minimize and close button
fr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; //set form's dock property to fill
fr.Show();
```