# Custom Control doesn't get MouseLeave event on minimize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I have a custom control which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control and I change the BackColor property on MouseEnter and MouseLeave events.  I use this to create a custom button class.  Everything works great except for one button whose click handler minimizes the main form containing all the buttons.  When the form is minimized via a click on this button the MouseLeave event for that button never fires (MouseUp, Click, and others still do though).

The problems start when I restore the application back to a Normal window state.  If I put the mouse over my custom minimize button, there is no MouseEnter event.  If I leave the button (without clicking) then I finally get a MouseLeave.  It basically seems like since the original MouseLeave never fired when the main form minimized, it doesn't think a MouseEnter should be possible.  So until you go in and back out again everything is basically broken.

I tried having my click handler manually call OnMouseLeave and that didn't change anything, though I didn't specify anything in particular in the EventArgs param if that's a critical part.

Any ideas on what I'm missing to get this to work?

EDIT:  Here is the complete project:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32742882/Button.zip

Turns out the issue is related to minimizing to a notifyIcon specifically, doesn't show up with a normal minimize.

EDIT:  Adding the code...

```
public class IconButton : Control
{
  public bool pressed;

  static readonly public bool boundingBox = false;
  static readonly Color darkGray = Color.FromArgb(255, 112, 112, 112);
  static readonly Color mediumGray = Color.FromArgb(255, 145, 145, 145);
  static readonly Color lightGray = Color.FromArgb(255, 178, 178, 178);
  static readonly Color hoverColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 209, 226, 242);
  static readonly Color backgroundColor =  boundingBox ? Color.FromArgb(255, 227, 227, 227) : SystemColors.Control;
  static readonly Color pressColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 212, 244);
  static readonly Color enabledTextColor = Color.Black;
  static readonly Color disabledTextColor = mediumGray;

  public IconButton()
  {
    this.BackColor = backgroundColor;
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.Margin = new Padding(2);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
  {
    if (Enabled)
    {
      this.BackColor = hoverColor;
    }
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
  {
    this.BackColor = backgroundColor;
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Enabled)
    {
      this.BackColor = pressColor;
    }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Enabled)
    {
      if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
      {
        this.BackColor = hoverColor;
      }
      else
      {
        this.BackColor = backgroundColor;
      }
    }
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
  }
}
```

FINAL EDIT:

So the problem was tied to calling ShowInTaskbar = false directly in the MainForm_SizeChanged handler.  This seemed to stop the event processing in its tracks and cause the issue.  So instead, I now do this line deferred 250ms and all seems well.  I'm open for suggestions as to how to make this cleaner though...

```
    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;

            notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "We got minimized";
            notifyIcon.Text = "Minimized";

            notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);

            TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            Task.Delay(250).ContinueWith(_ => {
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);
        }
        else if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason, you should not inherit from `Control`...inherit from `UserControl` instead.

Comment: @DonBoitnott why is that?  I simply followed the example Microsoft provided on building a custom button.  As you can see they inherit from Control.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172532(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Your first lesson in how bad their examples can be, my friend.  `UserControl` is designed to help you make your own Controls.  It takes some weight off your shoulders, where inheriting directly from `Control` might make you work harder than necessary.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same results.  I get mouse enter color change, I click it to minimize the form, a MouseLeave event fires, and when I restore the form, everything still works.

Comment: Not good advice in those comments.  Your snippet does not repro the problem, OnLeave() runs reliably if I let the button's Click event set the form's WindowState.  You may have a problem with the Capture property but that's nothing but a wild guess.

Comment: To be clear, the issue is NOT when you click the normal minimize button in the top right corner of the form.  The issue is when you use one of these IconButtons and set its Click handler to do WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; on the main form.  That is the only scenario that causes problems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @HansPassant and I both understood the minimizing issue, and neither of us reproduced the problem.  You have something else going on we don't see.  Showing a MessageBox at the wrong time can mess with things, too.

Comment: @LarsTech - thank you for your patience.  I originally assumed it was related to minimize specifically, but turns out if I do a normal minimize I don't see it either.  My app does a minimize to a notifyIcon and that's how I can repro it.  I have put a link to a complete project which shows the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it is tied to the ShowInTaskBar = true/false logic.  If I don't remove the app from the taskbar when I make the notifyIcon appear, then all is good.  But if I do the ShowInTaskBar = false at the same time then it gets into the funky state.  I suppose I could kick off a deferred execution of that part a fraction of a second later to see what that does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting the ShowInTaskbar to false, your *intention* is to actually *hide* the form, not minimize it.  To do that, you need to [intercept the minimizing event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/320145/719186), so try changing your code to something like this:

```
private void ToggleView() {
  if (this.Visible) {
    this.Hide();
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "We got minimized";
    notifyIcon.Text = "Minimized";
    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
  } else {
    this.Show();
    notifyIcon.Visible = false;
  }
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
  const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
  const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xf020;

  if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) {
    if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MINIMIZE) {
      m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
      ToggleView();
      return;
    }
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}

public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ToggleView();
}

private void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  ToggleView();
}
```

Note that I eliminated the Form1_SizeChanged event.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void Form1_Resize ( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    if ( WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized )
    {
        // code on minimized
    }
    else if(WindowsState == FormWindowState.Maximized) 
    {
        // code on maximized
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done this and that's how I got the information in my original post.  There is no MouseLeave when the minimize occurs nor is there a first MouseEnter after I restore the application and move back into this control.  From that point forward, moving out and in resumes firing those events as expected.  I will update my post with the code, but it is extremely simple.

Comment: But minimize shouldn't even fire MouseLeave... place another event handler that does the same thing as MouseLeave but onMinimize event